# Contact Form 7 Issue

Tags: forms, contacts

I tested the contact form on my website and it doesn't work. On the back end, it tells my I have the following issue "Unavailable names (name) are used for form controls." 
I couldn't figure out how to solve it after looking at their FAQs. My website address is www.garagedoormadisonwi.com and the code for my contact form is:

```
<div class="our-form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            [text* name class:form-control placeholder "Name"]
            <div class="input-bottom-line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            [email* email class:form-control placeholder "Eamil"]
            <div class="input-bottom-line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            [text* address class:form-control placeholder "Address"]
            <div class="input-bottom-line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            [tel* phone class:form-control placeholder "Phone"]
            <div class="input-bottom-line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            [textarea message class:form-control placeholder "Message"]
            <div class="input-bottom-line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="red-button bgcolor">
    [submit "submit"]
</button>
```

I'd appreciate if you can help me change it so it works.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the error message you provide:

```
"Unavailable names (name) are used for form controls."
```

It cleary tells us that there's something wrong with your form controls (i.e. input field) naming. Next step is to look how you've named those element.

What I would assume is that the problem appear due to simplictic naming convention you're using for your form elements. Quick search through CF7 documentation gives us a possible solution:

> The followings are parameter names that WordPress uses in a query: m, p, posts, w, cat, withcomments, withoutcomments, s, search, exact, sentence, calendar, page, paged, more, tb, pb, author, order, orderby, year, monthnum, day, hour, minute, second, name, category_name, tag, feed, author_name, static, pagename, page_id, error, attachment, attachment_id, subpost, subpost_id, preview, robots, taxonomy, term, cpage, post_type, and embed.

Soure: https://contactform7.com/faq/are-there-any-reserved-or-unavailable-words-for-the-name-of-an-input-field/

You can see that you cannot name your input control as "name".